# when i install koha on ubuntu then step 3 when i click on import show error shown blew

Tags: php, html, css

DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1 at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Objects.pm line 101

For help, please send mail to the webmaster ([no address given]), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Comment: Please provide a link to the instructions you're following.

Answer (score 0):

I was presented with the same error. It appears that the error is given in an enum column in the database. For MySQL you can solve it as follows (inside the MySQL database administrator):

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

When setting the mode with an empty string '' you are telling MySQL not to take into account some errors that arise when inserting data.

MySQL can operate in different modes, some modes are more restrictive than others, for example, some modes do not allow certain operations, such as division by zero or restrict the way in which the dates are represented in the database.

To see how the server is, you must log into MySQL from the command line:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If the MySQL server does not have a password (which is not recommended), omit the -p parameter. You can then check the mode with the following command

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

It will return more or less similar to this:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

You can find more information on this at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html